# splitting List every x times

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, split

Hellow,
I want to split an List(an ArrayList) after like every 7 Points in the List.
Example:

```
List<String> field = Lists.newArrayList("dsgtfsg","456hg","fg","s","fe","sdr","&&","fdg","hrdt","edts","dsf","a44","awfg");

field.split into (field_part1, field_part2, field_part3) after (7)
/* "dsgtfsg","456hg","fg","s","fe","sdr","&&" */   --> field_part1 
/* "fdg","hrdt","edts","dsf","a44","awfg" */ ---> field_part2
```

thank you guys,
~Corn

Comment: Tell us what you already did to solve your problem, and where you are stuck with your solution. Otherwise this questions does not show enough research effort.

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and provide us with a [mcve]

Comment: i would suggest returning an arraylist<arraylist<String>> to contain all your generated lists

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
List<String> field = Arrays.asList("dsgtfsg","456hg","fg","s","fe","sdr","&&","fdg","hrdt","edts","dsf","a44","awfg");

List<String> field_part_1 = field.subList(0, 6);
List<String> field_part_2 = field.subList(7, 12);
//List<String> field_part_3 = field.subList(...) and go on...
```

Otherwise, i agree with @Timmeey's point of view.

Comment: thanks :)Sorry for my bad asking-Style